# Why is the main table involved, since I configured the routing to use a custom routing table?

Tags: networking, ip, routing

I have the following situation:

```
- - - - - - -
| namespace |-------o      o------
- - - - - - -     vethY   ppp0
          vethX
```

where:

- `ppp0` is a PPP interface and its ip address is 192.168.100.169/24
- `vethX` is a virtual ethernet interface inside the namespace and its ip address is 10.0.0.3/24
- `vethY` is an other virtual ethernet inteface, its ip address is 10.0.0.5/24 and it is also the default gateway for the namespace

In fact the routing table into the namespace is the following:

```
$ sudo ip netns exec my_namespace ip route
default via 10.0.0.5 dev vethX
10.0.0.0/24 dev vethX proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.3
```

I want to use policy based routing in this scenario; in particular I want to use a custom routing table when the incoming interface of network packets is the `vethY` or the `ppp0` interface.

I've created the custom routing table with name '**T1**' adding the entry "T1" in the file `/etc/iproute2/rt_tables`.
Then I've added the policy routing rule that will tell the system when to use this new routing table.
So now the policy routing rules are:

```
$ ip rule
0:      from all lookup local
32764:  from all iif ppp0 lookup T1
32765:  from all iif vethY lookup T1
32766:  from all lookup main
32767:  form all lookup default
```

Then I've added the following rules into my custom table

```
$ ip route show table T1
default via 192.168.100.169 dev ppp0
10.0.0.0/24 dev vethY scope link
192.168.100.180 dev ppp0 scope link
```

The last line shows which is the other endpoint of the point-to-point link. 
Besides, the main routing table is empty.

With this configuration, if I am into the namespace and I ping 10.0.0.5, I don't receive answers (neither the ARP reply).
Request packets reach the vethY interface (I've seen that using wireshark) but no answer is generated.
If my arp cache is empty, when an arp request is sent no arp reply will be sent back.

Instead, if I add the rule
`10.0.0.0/24 dev vethY scope link` 
also into the main table, all the packets flow in the correct way.

Why I don't receive answers if I don't add this rule into the main table? 
Why is the main table involved, since I configured the routing to use T1 for all the packets coming either from vethY or ppp0?

Comment: I'm going to assume `veth5 == vethY`. I highly suspect reverse path filtering is your issue. Because traffic generated locally (on the host, but outside the namespace) will not be able to find a route to your `10.0.0.0/24` subnet, reverse path filtering drops it. You can confirm this by doing `sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.vethY.rp_filter=0`, and seeing if it starts working.

Comment: Yes, I'm sorry, I've just corrected my mistakes. @Patrick I've done the command you suggested but it doesn't work.If I use the main routing table instead of my custom table, everything works (also without the command you suggested). So I don't understand the reason why it doesn't work when I flush the main routing table and fill the custom one with the same rules.

Comment: Oh, I just noticed, your test is from the namespace to ping `10.0.0.5`, which looks to be the host address (outside of namespace). If there is no entry in table `main`, the host isn't going to be able to respond because it doesn't know how to route to the namespace.